# How to update the aws s3 updated files download file name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have uploaded files to s3 bucket with a UUID as a key for each file name ,
I have a requirement to keep the files key as the stored uuid but when download i need to have the downloaded file name as the actual file name eg: Foo.png

stored file on aws s3 -0e8221b9-9bf4-49d6-b0c0-d99e86f91f8e.png
Downloading file name should be :  foo.bar

I have tried with setting Content-Disposition meta Data but still when downloading the file contains the uuid.

[image]

Comment: your Content-Disposition filename is foo.bar but you want the file name to be testFile.png?. Also, share the code you have used.

Comment: @dassum updated the file name,Im testing this directly using aws console

Answer (score 0):

Perform the below changes and try.
Update `Content-Disposition = attachment;filename="abc.csv"`. Please note the file name is case sensitive and if you are using CDN then it will take some time after you apply the changes. After you update the metadata then download the file using the OBJECT URL. Direct download is not working.[image]. If I download the file using Object URL then the downloaded file name is abc.csv instead of test.csv.